# How WordPress permalink system works?

Tags: wordpress, url, content-management-system, blogs, permalinks

I am a php developer and i am currently developing a CMS/blog system. i want to add a permalink system like WordPress. i am curious about how WordPress parse permalink. For example, how to get data like `id` and `post name` from:

```
example.com/id/123/post/example/
```

In short, I want a system to get `id` and `post name` from the url. I want to enable users to change the permalink structure like WordPress using tags like:

```
id/%postid%/post/%postname%/
```

How do I get data in variables like `$id` and `$post_name` where values will `123` and `example`? Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

The commonly available apache module **mod_rewrite** can help you out with this.  What you do is write rewrite rules inside an .htaccess file, and through the rewrite, fancy structures that would have normally resembled a file system get sent to a PHP file as $_GET parameters.

For example, if you wanted to replace something like: `?reactor=13` into `/reactor/13/`

Write this rewrite rule in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule reactor/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?id=$1
```

Now, if instead of index.php you pull up /reactor/13/, your index.php file should see this in $_GET:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 13
)
```

Now, for your HTML code, it's up to you to craft URLs and obey your thought-out structure.

These rewrite rules can be confusing, but they follow a logical regex pattern.

WordPress takes a stronger approach than inserting these editing .htaccess files, to where they send everything to WP, and then WP solves / routes the rest through internal rules.

Comment: Where in the WP source does it process the links? I'm sure you're right (the mod_rewrite rules created are very simple/generic), but if I could see where this is supposed to happen it would help me diagnose a strange problem I'm having.

Comment: WP is actually too convoluted or abstracted to point to a single place. You can see this by looking at https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?q=permalink_structure&source=cc

Answer (score -2):

This depends on what server software you're using, but if your planning on using your scripts on Apache it, usually, involves using something called `mod_rewrite` and specifically a `.htaccess` file.

I would recommend starting by reading a tutorial on this subject. [As usual, Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?q=.htaccess+php+tutorial).