# Htaccess rewrite root folder request

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a possible way to point this:

```
domain.com/test
```

to:

```
domain.com/page.php?a=test
```

This has been bothering me for a while. Perhaps something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ page.php?a=$1 [NC]
```

I'm trying to point a request like `domain.com/test` to `page.php` and pass the parameter.

Comment: If there is a dot in url, for example `domain.com/test.php`, How do you plan to process the request.

Comment: @srain I'm trying to get it to show /test in the root directory.
If the request is domain.com/test i need it to point to page.php and pass the paramater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to map all the request, include `domain.com/test.php` to `domain.com/page.php?a=test.php`, you can:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /page.php?a=$1 [NC]
```

If you only want simply map the request path: `domain.com/test` to `domain.com/page.php?a=test`, you should:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z\-_]*)$ /page.php?a=$1 [NC]
```

Notice: After map, the url display in browser will still be `http://domain.com/test`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WordPress does this rather successfully with a combination of .htaccess and php... Here's another post that explains it pretty well:

[How WordPress permalink system works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314358/how-wordpress-permalink-system-works)

Here's a link that gives the actual WordPress .htaccess code for rewrites:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29