# How to load JSON with parameter in PHP, use one template and create multiple subpages in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, fetch

I am working on a project where I have Wordpress website that load some of its pages data from international database JSON.

**How it works now?**

On page e.g. `/houses/?id=123` Javascript call will check if JSON `houses.json/123` is available and fetch data that are shown on the page later.

As it is loaded in by JS it cannot be indexed by Google bot etc., so I need to rewrite it into PHP.

**How I need it to work?**

New page that should have address `/houses/123/` should be fetched by PHP directly.

**What I need now?**

I don't know how to set it that all subpages of /houses/ would have the same Wordpress template

**Ideal example:**

so  `/houses/123` will load `houses.json/123`
and `/houses/234` will load `houses.json/234`
both pages will use the same `page-house.php` template in Wordpress

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How WordPress permalink system works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314358/how-wordpress-permalink-system-works)